# Mysql workbech export column type json error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to export 1 query to a CSV file but with JSON type it gives an error, in my case, it is split into 2 columns.

Query :

```
SELECT tags FROM Questions AS a
```

Result of the query:

[image]

but when I export it to csv, I get:

[image]

It's easy to see the difference here, and there are columns with 2 or more objects that it is split into many columns.

Please help me.

Thanks all

Comment: Cast your value to string-type before selecting into outfile.

Comment: You can try removing the enclose string character when exporting to csv, and also when opening the csv file

Comment: @Akina how to remove when select query